# HTTP Query to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, paypal

I'm working with PayPal api and data that IPN receives is returned in http query

Similar to this

```
key=val&key2=val&key3[0].key1=val&key3[0].key2=val&key[1].key1=val&key[1].key2=val&key4=val
```

This is real response converted to JSON:

```
{
  "cmd": "_notify-validate",
  "transaction[0].is_primary_receiver": "true",
  "transaction[0].id_for_sender_txn": "xxx",
  "log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction": "false",
  "transaction[0].receiver": "xxx",
  "action_type": "PAY",
  "ipn_notification_url": "xxx",
  "transaction[1].paymentType": "SERVICE",
  "transaction[0].amount": "USD 19.50",
  "charset": "windows-1252",
  "transaction_type": "Adaptive Payment PAY",
  "transaction[1].id_for_sender_txn": "xxx",
  "transaction[1].is_primary_receiver": "false",
  "transaction[0].status": "Completed",
  "notify_version": "UNVERSIONED",
  "transaction[0].id": "xxx",
  "cancel_url": "xxx",
  "transaction[1].status_for_sender_txn": "Completed",
  "transaction[1].receiver": "xxx",
  "verify_sign": "xxx",
  "sender_email": "xxx",
  "fees_payer": "EACHRECEIVER",
  "transaction[0].status_for_sender_txn": "Completed",
  "return_url": "hxxx",
  "transaction[0].paymentType": "SERVICE",
  "transaction[1].amount": "USD 19.50",
  "reverse_all_parallel_payments_on_error": "false",
  "transaction[1].pending_reason": "NONE",
  "pay_key": "xxx",
  "transaction[1].id": "xxx",
  "transaction[0].pending_reason": "NONE",
  "status": "COMPLETED",
  "transaction[1].status": "Completed",
  "test_ipn": "1",
  "payment_request_date": "Sat Oct 24 00:00:00 PDT 2015"
}
```

How could I turn this to multidimensional array?

What I have currently:

```
parse_str(urldecode($req), $arr);
```

Which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [cmd] => _notify-validate
    [transaction] => Array
        (
            [0] => NONE
            [1] => Completed
        )

    [log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction] => false
    [action_type] => PAY
    [ipn_notification_url] => xxx
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [transaction_type] => Adaptive Payment PAY
    [notify_version] => UNVERSIONED
    [cancel_url] => xxx
    [verify_sign] => xxx
    [sender_email] => xxx
    [fees_payer] => EACHRECEIVER
    [return_url] => xxx
    [reverse_all_parallel_payments_on_error] => false
    [pay_key] => xxx
    [status] => COMPLETED
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [payment_request_date] => Sat Oct 24 00:00:00 PDT 2015
)
```

Here is the raw response ($req)

```
cmd=_notify-validate&transaction%5B0%5D.is_primary_receiver=true&transaction%5B0%5D.id_for_sender_txn=xxx1&log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction=false&transaction%5B0%5D.receiver=xxx&action_type=PAY&ipn_notification_url=xxx&transaction%5B1%5D.paymentType=SERVICE&transaction%5B0%5D.amount=USD+19.50&charset=windows-1252&transaction_type=Adaptive+Payment+PAY&transaction%5B1%5D.id_for_sender_txn=xxx&transaction%5B1%5D.is_primary_receiver=false&transaction%5B0%5D.status=Completed&notify_version=UNVERSIONED&transaction%5B0%5D.id=xxx&cancel_url=xxxtransaction%5B1%5D.status_for_sender_txn=Completed&transaction%5B1%5D.receiver=xxx&verify_sign=xxx&sender_email=xxx&fees_payer=EACHRECEIVER&transaction%5B0%5D.status_for_sender_txn=Completed&return_url=xxx&transaction%5B0%5D.paymentType=SERVICE&transaction%5B1%5D.amount=USD+19.50&reverse_all_parallel_payments_on_error=false&transaction%5B1%5D.pending_reason=NONE&pay_key=xxx&transaction%5B1%5D.id=xxx&transaction%5B0%5D.pending_reason=NONE&status=COMPLETED&transaction%5B1%5D.status=Completed&test_ipn=1&payment_request_date=Sat+Oct+24+15%3A42%3A38+PDT+2015
```

So clearly I cant use parse_str for this.
How could I parse response to multidimensional array?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the actual `$req` that you used, please? Also, note that the output you've already posted is already a multidimensional array. It doesn't seem to correspond to your input though...

Comment: I edited raw response to question.